# Unmanaged call stack in c# application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging, pinvoke, callstack

I am getting an access violation error in an unmanaged dll I am writing, but when I try to debug It in a c# application it will only get the last frame of the call stack in Visual Studio's debug window.

I have debug->exceptions->System.AccessViolationException set to break the debugger when it is thrown.

```
myunmanaged.dll!ViolatingFunc() Line 100 + 0xc bytes
- - - -
[external code] //myunmanaged.dll!function that I want to see
- - - -
somecsharp.exe!com.somewhere.Form1.CallFuncThatCallsViolator();
```

I was hoping to walk up the unmanaged stack to see where the data gets turned to garbeldegook.
Is this possible?

**Answered**
[image]

Enabling unmanaged debugging is step 1, but to get me all the way there I enabled microsoft symbols.

that made my stack trace look more like this:

```
myunmanaged.dll!ViolatingFunc() 
- - - -
myunmanaged.dll!SomeFunc2() 
- - - -
myunmanaged.dll!SomeFunc()
- - - -
[managed to unmanaged code transition]
- - - -
somecsharp.exe!com.somewhere.Form1.CallFuncThatCallsViolator();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is.  You need to debug your application in 'Mixed-mode'.  Right click on the project, select the 'Debug' tab and check 'Enable unmanaged code debugging'.  You will see managed and native frames.

[image: mixed mode debugging]

**Edit**: As ChrisO mentions not having MS symbols can make native debugging weird. Add the following to your symbols path for Windows symbols: `http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

Comment: And it's best to load the debug symbols as well, from the microsoft symbol server, sometimes the call stacks look awful until you do so.

Comment: @ChrisO That is a good point.  I will add that to the answer.

Comment: Is that the checkbox "enable unmanaged code debugging"? that is already set for me, I can see the frame where the problem occurs, but I cannot see what happened between than and the last managed call

Comment: @TomFobear You might also want to enable 'First chance exceptions'.  I would like to also state though that Mixed-mode debugging can be tricky.  The debugger has many issues with mixed-mode so if you are still seeing something weird, I would try to debug the process separately as native then as managed.

Comment: I have one exception check for "thrown": System.AccessViolationException. that gets me to the frame in the dll with the faulty access.. but nothing above it. I have loaded the Microsoft Symbols as ChrisO suggested but not sure that will give me what I want - the frames are calls made in my dll.