# Find cause of Access violation

Tags: c#, winforms, access-violation

I am trying to create a game in WinForms but after running a while it throws an Access-violation-Exception

I tried changing some settings as found in answers to similar questions but none worked.

If it helps: I use no P/Invoke other than this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
{
    try
    {
        int state = 0;
        short retVal = GetKeyState((int)key);
        if ((retVal & 0x8000) == 0x8000)
            state |= 1;
        if ((retVal & 1) == 1)
            state |= 2;
        return 1 == (state & 1);
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invader: IsKeyDown failed:\r\n" + e1.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

It simply exits with `Exception thrown at 0x76C391EA (msvcrt.dll) in LaptopSimulator2015.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0D39864A. occurred` after about a minute.
Is this my fault?
What can I do to find out where the Exception is thrown?

EDIT: It somehow fixed itself after moving the solution folder somewhere else. Seems to have been caused by Visual Studio.

Comment: Firstly try to debug and find out which line in your code is throwing the excpetion.

Comment: @dedecos It doesn't show any line and (if I try to continue) it just keeps crashing with the same Exception until i kill the process. All information I seem to get is which functions are run often

Comment: Open the Call Stack window under the Debug menu and check which is the last called function in the call stack when the exception happens.

Comment: @dedecos Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/50yfvl6blha5izh/Unbenannt.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Can't you see more calls in the call stack besides the ones showed in your screenshot?

Comment: @dedecos No, thats it.

Comment: Follow these steps to enhance the output of the call stack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915495/unmanaged-call-stack-in-c-sharp-application

Comment: By doing that you will be able to see a cleaner and meaningful call stack.

Comment: @dedecos https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxyidiu9upzbmu8/Unbenannt1.PNG?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/ylxo5xlr2seqj4t/Unbenannt2.PNG?dl=0 https://www.dropbox.com/s/dajyjjjujiwuk40/Unbenannt3.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Well, as there are unmanaged functions in the call stack try to set a breakpoint here `short retVal = GetKeyState((int)key);` and step over it. Check if the exception is thrown by executing this line.

Comment: @dedecos Setting a breakpoint might not be a good idea as the function is executed ~200 times per second, I do use it in a seperate program that only consists of the minigame that uses the function without any problems if that helps

Comment: I'm searching what should be done in a case like this, but as I never faced such a scenario I can only try to point possible solutions to you. It seems like using .Net Native can help you here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-native-deep-dive-debugging-into-interop-code/